# Home Page Shows as URL in Browser Tab, how do I set my blog title as the tab text?

Tags: html

I was trying to change it so that my blog title appears after the page title for posts. My normal posts are now OK, but the homepage shows the URL in the browser tab, instead of my blog title. This is the code that I added:

```
<title><b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<title><data:blog.pageName/> | <data:blog.title/></title> <b:else/>
<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
</b:if></title>
```

Edit: I use Blogger, sorry if I have explained it wrong, my skills and knowledge are basic.

Comment: What templating engine / framework are you using ? `<b:if>` is not a HTML tag.

Comment: Hi, I use blogger

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation ?

Comment: www.latoyah.co.uk

Comment: That is not a link to a documentation. The documentation is the manual that provides informations about something. In your case, how the templating works.

Comment: I have it, but it is a text file on my PC. How do I share with you?

Comment: Again, your code is not the documentation. For example : here is the documentation about the HTML `title` tag : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title If there is no documentation, where did you see the tag `b:if` ?

Comment: I think I have it: http://blog.themexpose.com/carolina-blogger-template-documentation/

Comment: Found the b:if online when searching how to change the blog title to be at the end of a post.

Comment: I am afraid there is nothing in your link that is about the `b:if` tag. I am not really sure what is the final goal, but if you just want to have your blog name in the tab title, just add `<title>Your blog's name here</title>` in the `head` tag, and that should be all you need.

Comment: The b:if was found online to move the blog title from being at the start of posts, to being at the end. My blog has the title defined within the code, but for some reason on the homepage it only shows the URL in tabs, instead of the blog title.

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation I linked, the `title` tag is supposed to be *between* `<head>` and `</head>` because it is not meant to be visible in the page itself. The tag's position between the `head` tags doesn't matter.

Comment: It has that code in there to define the blog title, but as I mentioned, on the homepage only, the tab shows only the URL.

Comment: Have you tried what [this article](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/change-title-blogspot-post-29972.html) suggests ?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood me. I have an issue with the Homepage (https://www.latoyah.co.uk) showing the URK in the browser tab, instead of the blog title 'Sugar Pink Food'. In all actually posts it displays correctly. I followed this article https://www.bloggertipstricks.com/post-title-before-blog-title.html

Comment: On your website home page, there is no `<title>` tag.

Comment: There is within the code, so what do I need to do?

Comment: I do not know how Blogger works, but maybe you need to set the web page title somewhere in the blogger managment interface. Sorry, I cannot help you more, I do not have enough informations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me on [this blog](https://www.thecollectionatoz.com) I wrote.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
<title><data:blog.pageTitle/></title>
<b:else/>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;error_page&quot;'>
<title><data:blog.pageName/> - <data:blog.title/></title>
</b:if></b:if>

<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;error_page&quot;'>
<title>Page Not Found - <data:blog.title/></title>
</b:if>
```

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.